# JQuery Dialog Modal Box Frame

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dialog

I am trying to use a dialog element on my page, but I am having some issues.  It would appear that the box itself is not showing up.  I have an iframe inside the dialog that is working properly (aside from some sizing issues), but the title bar of the box and (sometimes) the buttons are not shown.  I have seen online that the cause of this is typically that the JQuery UI css file is not included, but I don't think that is the problem here, as I have the link, which was copied from another page that is creating dialog boxes properly.  I can't decide if it is relevant or not, but I am creating the pages in SharePoint Designer, and it is using two different standards to evaluate the pages, one of which (the non-working one) claims that the `<link>` tag is an error, saying that 'In XHTML 1.0 Strict the  tag cannot contain a .'  However, there is no `<div>` around the `<link>` tag, and the designer also says that many of the SharePoint-created tabs named `<SharePoint:...>` are not allowed in this version of XHTML.  The code that creates the dialog is included for reference:

```html
<div id='am_schedDetailModal' title='Details'>
  <div class='ui-widget'></div>
</div>
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#am_schedDetailModal").dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        modal: true,
        buttons: {
            'Close': function() {
                $(this)
                    .html('')
                    .dialog('close');
            }
        }
    });
});


function onClick() {
    var width = window.innerWidth ||
         document.documentElement.clientWidth ||
         document.body.clientWidth;
    var height = window.innerHeight ||
         document.documentElement.clientHeight ||
         document.body.clientHeight;

    $('#am_schedDetailModal').dialog('option', 'width', Math.floor(width * .7));
    $('#am_schedDetailModal').dialog('option', 'height', Math.floor(height * .7));


    $('#am_schedDetailModal div').html("<iframe id='am_mdl_iframe' src='" + input + "' height='100%' width='100%'>");
    $('#am_schedDetailModal').dialog('open');
}
```

Any help with this problem would be appreciated.

**EDIT:**  I am fairly certain that the `<link>` containing the CSS is simply not being loaded, since the iframe shows up wit the appropriate `<div>`s and such surrounding it that should be showing up with the modal box.  I still don't understand, however, why the CSS is not loading.

Comment: This seems to work: http://jsfiddle.net/RQfAK/1/

Comment: Yeah, I tried a similar fiddle, and it worked fine for me too.  But for some reason, the CSS just isn't wanting to load on this page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I have no idea what the reason was, but I found a new place to put the `<link>` tag, and now it is loading properly.  If anyone else is having this problem with a SharePoint web-part page, try putting the tag in the most obvious spot that I could possibly have overlooked- the `<asp:Content>` tag that contains the `<meta>` tags.